# Error adding Icon^M file to file name cache

Tags: osx

On MacOS, if a folder has custom icon, there would be an invisible file named Icon^M in it. `^M` being carriage return.  Kindly refer to https://superuser.com/questions/298785/icon-file-on-os-x-desktop for more details about such a file.

If I try to add the parent folder with M-x file-cache-add-directory, I get error `"Filecache: file /xxx/xxx/Icon does not exist"`

Is it possible to let Emacs ignore this file?

Comment: Curious. Emacs might be (undesirably) applying EOL normalisation? In the output of `directory-files` the carriage return (which is the old-style MacOS EOL syntax) has been converted into a newline (which is Unix EOL syntax).

Comment: Is `Icon^M` a file or a folder (directory)? Twice you call it a file, but it sounds like you are trying to add it as a directory using `M-x file-cache-add-directory` (?).

Comment: @Drew I was trying to add its parent folder with `file-cache-add-directory`

Comment: That's what I guessed, but you might want to edit to say that more clearly. Thx.

Comment: David Dai: please `M-x report-emacs-bug` about `directory-files` converting the trailing carriage-return into a newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Icon^M` is a file, and you want to ignore it, it looks like you can customize option `file-cache-filter-regexps` to do that.  Have you tried?

> **`file-cache-filter-regexps`** is a variable defined in `filecache.el`.
>
> Its value is
>
> `("~$" "\\.o$" "\\.exe$" "\\.a$" "\\.elc$" ",v$" "\\.output$" "\\.$" "#$" "\\.class$")`
>
> Documentation:
>
> List of regular expressions used as filters by the file cache.
>
> File names which match these expressions will not be added to the cache.
>
> Note that the functions `file-cache-add-file` and `file-cache-add-file-list`
>   do not use this variable.
>
> You can customize this variable.

Comment: You do still need to convert the \r to a \n, but this is a nicer solution than my suggestion. e.g. `(add-to-list 'file-cache-filter-regexps "Icon\n$")`

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in `directory_files_internal` the carriage return gets converted into a newline, which triggers the mismatch.

You can work around this with a custom replacement command that anticipates this issue:

```el
(defun my-file-cache-add-directory (directory)
  "Add all files in DIRECTORY to the file cache.

Exclude files ending in newlines, on account of a bug whereby filenames
ending in a carriage return (such as OSX Icon^M files) are corrupted to
end in a newline, triggering a filename mismatch."
  (interactive (list (read-directory-name "Add files from directory: "
                                          nil nil t)))
  (file-cache-add-directory directory "[^\n]\\'"))
```

Comment: the regex you used in above script looks very confusing to me. could you help me understand what `\\'` does?

Comment: `M-x elisp-index-search RET \' RET`. The double-backslash in the code is on account of the double-quoted string read syntax (and noting also that the `\n` is a string escape code, not a regexp escape code, which is why that one only has a single backslash).